# XSLT Unable to store nodes from a particular position to last into a variable

Tags: xslt

I am trying to split an XSLT variable nodes into two different nodes. Let say I have more than 50 nodes in a variable, Parent. I want to store first 50 in a variable (First50) and rest of the nodes into another variable (After50).

The problem is I am able to store First50 currectly. However unable to get After50.

```
<xsl:variable name="check" select="count($Parent) - 50"/>

<xsl:if test="$check &gt; 0">

<xsl:variable name="First50" select="$Parent[position() &lt;= 50]"/>

<xsl:variable name="After50" select="$Parent[51 &lt;= position()]"/>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "unable to get After50"?  With the code you've given above both the `First50` and `After50` variables will be locally scoped to the `<xsl:if>` and will not be accessible outside that element.

Comment: I'm not convinced you need the `<xsl:if>` at all though, just set both variables unconditionally, and if there are fewer than 51 nodes in `$Parent` then `After50` will be an empty node set, and you can test for that condition at the points where you need to know about it.

Comment: Thanks for the coments I meant Those variables inside If Loop I am using... Something to do with select="$Parent[51 &lt;= position()]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "1 to 50" and "50 to end()" in predicates